# AudioVideoPlayback.dll is currently in use

Tags: installation, directx, sdk

When I try to install the June 2010 DirectX SDK, I receive this message:

> The DirectX component "Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll" is currently in use by other applications.  You must close any applications using the component before setup can continue.

I have closed everything and still get the error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue by running the installer (`DXSDK_Jun10.exe`) as an administrator. Right-click the `.exe` and choose "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if any program is listed when you try `tasklist /m AudioVideoPlayback.dll` in a command prompt.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it said no tasks were running that used that dll.

Comment: It's probably giving you the wrong error message then. But, have you tried installing it in Safe Mode?